# roscore runns only as root ubuntu 12.04 fuerte

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, root, roscore, sudo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I cannot start the roscore without root rights.
I am getting the following message:

```
me/max/.ros/log/f45ff58e-a35a-11e1-9b99-001fc603da02/roslaunch-rue-3228.log Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile. Press Ctrl-C to interrupt Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/rosversion", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2711, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: rospkg==1.0.2 Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion ros] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="rosversion ros" name="rosversion"/>
```

running the core with root rights works?

```
sudo -i
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
roscore
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32bit with ros fuerte and I installed everything based on the ppa server.

Any ideas?

greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34471/roscore-runns-only-as-root-ubuntu-12.04-fuerte/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2012-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-05-21**:
In a non-root shell, what do you get for `rosversion ros`

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-21**:
Are you sourcing setup.bash in both cases?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-21**:
PPA server? You mean either packages.ros.org or one of the mirrors listed on the wiki ( http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Installation/UbuntuMirrors )?

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2012-05-21**:
@dornhege
rosversion ros chrashes as well, if I run it as root it gives me 1.8.7

@joq
yes i am sourcing the setup.bash in both cases

@Eric
With PPA server I mean the packages.ros.org -> no mirror was used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out :-)
The problem was a old attempt to install ros from sources with *pip and easy_install*
as it is described on http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source . The attempt places stuff under /usr/local/bin and since I was executing some of the commands with sudo the rights we set to root only.
Installing the fuerte ros based on the ppa worked well but old binaries under /usr/local/bin where already placed within the search path before the others and executed instead. This leaded to the permission problems.

The solution was to remove:
do delete the related old stuff

```
cd /usr/local/bin
rm -rf pip pip-2.7 rosco rosdep rosdep-gbp-brew rosdep-source rosinstall roslocate rosversion rosws virtualenv
cd /usr/local/lib
rm -rf python2.7 
# sudo apt-get purge python-pip python-dev build-essential # should not be nessesary but I dit it anyway
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-desktop
```

Greetings

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) with karma: 847 on 2012-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2